# Split Custom Validator into multiple Functions Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

```
    export class FormFieldErrorExample {
      email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email, this.lengthValidator]);

      getErrorMessage() {
        return this.email.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
            this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' :
                'minimum length should be greater than 10';
      }
      lengthValidator(control : AbstractControl){

        if(control.value.length <10)    
        return {lengthError : true};
        else return this.anotherValidator(control);
      }
anotherValidator(control: AbstractControl){

 return {lengthError : true};
}
```

I have tried to split the validator into another function but getting an error like 'Cannot read property '**anotherValidator**' of undefined'.
How can i split the validator into multiple functions and pass the **control** properly

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psfasq-5yxaln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the context of `this` to your customvalidator `lengthValidator` using [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email, this.lengthValidator.bind(this)])
```

Comment: Thanks you saved my day!! .bind(this) works perfectly.